# All I see is white when I play my Godot game

Tags: 3d, godot

Every time I play all I see is white, what is show below. My Camera view for my character looks just fine when I hit preview in the editor.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEoqZ.png)

I wondered if maybe it was stuck in the map (I haven't applied the textures yet so everything is still white). However, when I removed the map entirely it still had that problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems the flag `Current` is not checked in your Camera3D properties.

This flag means that the Camera3D will be used as viewpoint when running the game. With the flag disabled the game will use the default viewpoint, with explains why the view you are seeing is different from the editor.

Comment: Thank you very much. I asked a few people for help but they didn't know what to do. Anyway that fixed it. I would upvote but apparently I need more reputation on this site before I can do that